# Shopify App get's caught in a redirect Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, shopify, shopify-app

Running on my dev environment, via ngrok, I get a redirection loop when trying to return to the app a few days after installation as a test store. My App is not embedded.

I click into the store, apps and click to open the app. It gets into a redirection loop.

1. /shopify/login
2. /auth/shopify
3. /shopify/dash
4. /shopify/login?return_to=%2Fshopify%2Fdash /auth/shopify
5. /shopify/dash

etc.

I have my Shopify_App engine added like this

```
Routes:
mount ShopifyApp::Engine, at: '/shopify'
```

Shopify_app.rb initializer:

```
ShopifyApp.configure do |config|
  config.application_name = "PucttoShopifyApp"
  config.api_key = ENV['SHOPIFY_API_KEY']
  config.secret = ENV['SHOPIFY_API_SECRET']
  config.old_secret = ""
  config.scope = "read_products, write_themes, read_themes" 
  config.embedded_app = false 
  config.after_authenticate_job = false
  config.api_version = "2020-10"
  config.shop_session_repository = 'Shop'
  config.allow_jwt_authentication = true
  config.allow_cookie_authentication = false
  config.root_url = '/shopify'
  # config.after_authenticate_job = { job: "Shopify::AfterAuthenticateJob", inline: true }
end
```

And then the app runs in namespace shopify

```
module Shopify
  class ApplicationController < AuthenticatedController
  end
end

class AuthenticatedController < ApplicationController   
  include ShopifyApp::Authenticated
end
```

With my shop model

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ShopifyApp::ShopSessionStorage

  def api_version
    ShopifyApp.configuration.api_version
  end
end
```

OmniAuth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use(OmniAuth::Builder) do
# frozen_string_literal: true
# TODO: needed?
provider :shopify,
  ShopifyApp.configuration.api_key,
  ShopifyApp.configuration.secret,
  scope: ShopifyApp.configuration.scope,
  callback_path: '/shopify/auth/shopify/callback',
  setup: lambda { |env|
    strategy = env['omniauth.strategy']

    shopify_auth_params = strategy.session['shopify.omniauth_params']&.with_indifferent_access
    shop = if shopify_auth_params.present?
      "https://#{shopify_auth_params[:shop]}"
    else
      ''
    end

    strategy.options[:client_options][:site] = shop
    strategy.options[:old_client_secret] = ShopifyApp.configuration.old_secret
    strategy.options[:per_user_permissions] = strategy.session[:user_tokens]
  }
end
```

In my App Setup, I have
Allowed redirection URL(s)
https://xxxx.ngrok.io/shopify/auth/shopify/callback

App URL
https://xxxx.ngrok.io/shopify/dash

Rails rails (6.1.3) shopify_app (18.0.1) Ruby 2.7.2

Looking at the Issues list, there are other people having similar troubles.  How should I start debugging this, is it a Gem error or something I have set up incorrectly?

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/1281
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/1256
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/1053

Update.
/dash goes to

```
class Shopify::DashController < Shopify::ApplicationController

  def dash
  end

end

module Shopify
  class ApplicationController < AuthenticatedController
    layout 'shopify'   
   end
end

class AuthenticatedController < ApplicationController
  include ShopifyApp::Authenticated
end
```

## DEMO

I've added a demo of it not working.

https://github.com/asecondwill/shopifydemo3

Comment: ````/shopify/dash```` what is this?

Comment: This is the home page of my shopify app.  a dashboardy thing

Comment: @HymnZzy - i added some notes.